# Как поменять содержание формы с помощью React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Не получается поменять содержание формы с помощью React Router
Первая форма загружается нормально, при переходе на вторую не отрисовывается компонент, хотя должна была отрисоваться таже самая форма

```js
const Login = ( props ) => {
  const { match } = props;
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation ();


  return (
    <LoginContainer>
      <LoginContainerTitle>{ t ( 'loginPage.loginTitle' ) }</LoginContainerTitle>
      <LoginContentWrapper>
        
        <CustomForm>
          <Switch>
            <Route path={ `${ match.path }` } component={ LoginForm } />
            <Route path='/registration' component={ LoginForm }/>
          </Switch>

          

        </CustomForm>
        
        <LoginContainerButtonWrapper>
          <CustomButton orangeSoft>{ t ( 'loginPage.loginButton' ) }</CustomButton>
        </LoginContainerButtonWrapper>
        <LoginNewCustomerContainer>
          <LoginNewCustomerText>{ t ( 'loginPage.loginQuestion' ) }</LoginNewCustomerText>
          <LoginNewCustomerLink
            to={ '/registration' }
          >{ t ( 'loginPage.registrationLink' ) }</LoginNewCustomerLink>
        </LoginNewCustomerContainer>


      </LoginContentWrapper>
    </LoginContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Можешь добавить больше кода? Или ссылку на Github? Не видно как Links настроены.

Answer (score 0):

Убедиться что компонент находится внутри тэга `BrowserRouter`

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

return (
<BrowserRouter>
// твой код компонента
</BrowserRouter>)
```